# Check out banner not appearing in Word past 250 characters

Tags: sharepoint-online

When opening documents from SharePoint it normally prompts to Check-out in Word via a yellow banner. I've noticed if the file path is over 250 characters this banner does not appear. You can checkout directly in SharePoint though. Is this a Windows limitation?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Word, Excel, and PowerPoint don't respect MAX_PATH. You will want to keep your pathing <250 characters in Windows Explorer for path + file name + extension.